# Python Transparent PNG

Tags: python, png, transparency

can someone tell me whats wrong with this please,

i'm trying to show a png that has transparency, on a canvas.

In photoshop when i save the png as png-24 the image is blank, when i save the image as png-8 (no transparancy) I can see the image.

```
from Tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

maxWidth  = "320"
maxHeight = "240"
imgFile   = "images/skin.png"

root = Tk()
root.title("MediaPlayer")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
root.geometry(maxWidth+'x'+maxHeight)

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="black", width=maxWidth, height=maxHeight)
canvas.pack()

image  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=imgFile) 
canvas.create_image(160, 120, image=image)

root.mainloop()
```

im using OSX 10.10 and python 2.7.9

Comment: Your code works for me on Windows. Here's a [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/Transparent%20PNG.png) and here's the [test image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/skin.png) - a 24-bit png with transparency that I created in Photoshop, It must be an OS issue or an image issue. Please add the image to your question (or add link to it to somewhere we can download a copy).

Comment: I get nothing with your images also, so it must be an issue with something else, is it because im using Pillow and not PIL (PIL woulnt install)?

Comment: To be clear, the first image is a screenshot. The second image is what the program is reading. I'm also using using Pillow (2.7.0 and Python 2.7.9). Could be a Pillow issue since you're on a different OS.

Comment: Yes Im using the second image , I still do ont see anything.

Comment: Please provide a link to your image. You can use something like http://imgur.com, http://tinypic.com, or one of the many other free image hosting sites to do this since you can't add images to your question yet.

Comment: I Just tried it on my work Mac with a new image, using python2.6 and Pillow2.6 its still the same. here is the link to an image: http://i.imgur.com/1LnxH4I.png

Comment: Your imgur image [appears to work](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5508445/stackoverflow/Transparent%20PNG2.png) properly for me, too. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a [version of Pillow 2.7.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0) for Python 2.6 (cp26) on OSX, I suggest you upgrade to Python 2.7 then to Pillow 2.7.0.

Comment: I'm using the 2.7 version at home and 2.6 at work, nether work for me, is this just a mac os issue? Did you install zLIB before pillow I wonder if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Didn't need to install zLIB, just a GnuWin32 distribution of libtiff — which likely is irrelevant to the your problem. I'm using 32-bit Python, like most other folks still do, even though we have 64-bit processors.